# sql select sum off of two where clauses

Tags: sql, select, sum, where-clause

```
SELECT Projects.Projectid, Projects.ProjectNumber, Projects.ProjectName,
       Projects.ProjectBudgetedIS, Projects.ProjectSpentIS, 
       Projects.ProjectBudgetedBusiness, Projects.PorjectSpentBusiness, Project.Status,
       ProjectStatus.Status AS Expr1

FROM Projects 
     INNER JOIN ProjectStatus ON  Projects.Status = ProjectStatus.StatusID 
WHERE Projects.Status = @Status
```

So what I want to do is take the sum of a table called invoices which has a field called `ISorBusiness` and a field called `totalspent` and store that data into the projects tabel in the appropriate field.  So that when I get an invoice that is charged to the IS it takes that amount and rolls it into the `Projects.ProjectSpentIS` and if I get a invoice that is to the business it rolls it into the `Projects.ProjectBudgetedBusiness`.

I know this should be easy and sorry for the noobish question.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you actually _need_ to store the aggregate data?  Does it take a **lot** of resources to do so?  Storing data like that is a violation of normalization practices, and _will_ bite you very quickly.  You also seem to be claiming to want to roll it into what is probably the wrong field (shouldn't it be `ProjectSpentBusiness`).  Personally, I'd want to refactor the design just slightly, so I'm not limited to strictly 2 categories (even if I only ever use 2).

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN (IsOrBusiness = 'IS') THEN totalSpent ELSE 0 END) AS IsSpent, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN (IsOrBusiness = 'Business') THEN totalSpent ELSE 0 END) AS BusinessSpent
FROM Invoices
```

Obviously the usage depends on whether you are trying to write an insert query or select this data as part of the select query you have posted.